# Programmatically Change A Property Of A Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to be able to programmatically update the value of the "Tags" property of my new Word Document using VBA. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this with the [Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196862.aspx). I can only see these when the document is closed. By experimentation I see that the the property that appears as "Tag" in Windows Explorer is called "Keywords" in VBA. I set a couple of tags in Windows Explorer and observed that they are separated by semicolons when I look at the Keyword property in VBA. Based on that, here's the code to add two tags to `ThisDocument`:

```
ThisDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords") = "test; test2"
```